# sphinx: how to search for a phrase with wildcard?

Tags: sphinx

I have a phrase "my name is bob". I want to match it by querying "my n".

How my query should look like? What config should I have?

min_prefix_len and min_prefix_len did not give any expecting results.

I had min_word_len set to 2, but changing it to 1 did not help either.

expand_keywords 1/2 had made no difference.

Here's my index config:

```
index track
{
    source                  = track
    path                    = /var/lib/sphinx/track
    min_word_len            = 1
    docinfo                 = extern
    mlock                   = 1
    morphology              = none
    expand_keywords         = 1
}
```

The queries i tried:

- "my n*"
- "my n"*
- my n
- "my n" | my n*
- "my n" | "my n*" | my n*

No matter what, I cannot match "my name ...".

Answer (score 3):

```
min_word_len = 1
min_prefix_len = 1
expand_keywords = 0
```

Need `min_prefix_len` to enable wildcard searches. But want `expand_keywords` off, as that makes all keywords have wildcards on them.

Then can just do

```
"my n*"
```

Comment: If I have a RT index and edit the above into my sphinx.conf and then do searchd --stop, searchd (restart it), I should be able to query with where match('wor*') and get 'word' back right? This isn't currently happening and I'm wondering if I'm missing a step.

Comment: The index will need recreating from scratch. I dont think can just change these settings on a live index. For a 'indexer' created index, can just use it recreate the index. For the RT index, you will have to delete it, change the settings, and then re-insert all the data again. There is "ALTER RTINDEX index RECONFIGURE" but dont think it will help